# Multiples sounds (audio and video) in Samsung SmartTV App

Tags: html, flash, audio, video, samsung-smart-tv

I'm writing a smart hub app for my project (novosga.org - support system), where the objective is create a display to show the customer ticket number. In the app I've a video (with sound) and play sounds (beeb and voice) when call the next customer. All works fine in the emulator.

However when I install the app in my TV the second audio to play is muted. If the video start after the beeb, the beeb dont work, and vice-versa.

Samsung smart tv have any issue with multiples sounds?

**Tests**

- HTML5: tag audio + tag video
- SAMSUNG-INFOLINK-PLAYER (video) + HTML5 (audio)
- SAMSUNG-INFOLINK-PLAYER (video) + SWF (audio)
- Multiple SWF
- Single SWF

**[UPDATE]**

I've resolved this issue using the same pluginPlayer spliting in the video time and audio time.

Comment: In the "tests" section you seem to state that you've tried this with both HTML5 and Flash... and the same problem happens no matter which technologies you use?

Comment: Yes. All tests works fine in the emulator, but not in the tv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Samsung Smart TV is not support parallel playback of several media files.

You can workaround it by playing sound and video in one SWF. Flash Player will mix audio and you will be able to hear it on TV

Comment: Thanks for reply Ivan. However I've tried a single SWF using flash.media.Video and flash.media.Audio without success. How I can do it work using Flash?

Comment: I used class `Sound` to play mp3 in game application and several mp3 played in parallel.